# Check if the Snp position co-localise with genomic region of the genes (start and end)

Tags: r

```
refsnp_id  SNps_pos   Gene-id          chr       start       end            
rs1713712  2244722    ENSG00000000457   1        169818772  169863408
rs1739855  1298561   ENSG00000000460    1        169631245  169823221
rs1749951  1295309   ENSG00000000460      1        169631245 169823221
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: This type of question is much better suited to https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/. Whilst many bioinformaticians use stackoverflow, your question typically won't get an answer unless it is focused on programming (designing bioinformatics software), not using bioinformatics software (e.g. how to use bcftools / awk / etc). Also, to improve your chance of getting an answer, please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example with sample input and expected output.

Comment: Hi Jerry, you need to provide a better input/output sample if you want others to give you a solution for this. What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Do you want to check whether for each row `$2` is within the range of `$5` and `$6` ?